# What are the names of random variables in conditional probabilities?

Tags: probability, random-variable, conditional-probability

In a conditional probability like `p(A|B)`, what `A` and `B` are called?

Comment: $A, ~B$ are random variables?

Comment: Yes of course, but what they are called? like "conditionally upon" or something?

Comment: Amin, the phrase usage is correct.

Comment: or perhaps $A$ and $B$ are events.  You would say something like "the conditional probability/density of $A$ given $B$".  While *conditional probability* and *conditional distribution* are meaningful phrases, I am not convinced that *conditional random variable* or *conditional event* are.

Comment: If I *had* to call these variables something -- and I don't think I ever have -- I would consider referring to $B$ as the *conditioning variable* and $A$ as the *conditioned variable.*